# Locked question - where is the discussion?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073041/what-is-so-wrong-with-thinking-of-real-numbers-as-infinite-decimals) is currently [marked as locked](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2073041/timeline):

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being
>   resolved. For more info visit meta.

.... so I came to meta, looking for discussion about this locked post, but I don't see any.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: No, in principle you're in the right place. The question was taken from [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/decimals.html), without attribution, and I've locked it until it has been decided how to deal with the problem.

Comment: The text you quote is boiler plate text, it is not intended to imply that there is already some meta post. Another option to understand it is as "if you want more info/have questions about it, you can ask about it on meta." The likely reason why it is locked seems to be explained in a comment. Copied content.

Comment: Same situation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072977/why-study-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces-in-the-abstract-if-they-are-all-isomo), by the way. [Source](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/vspaces.html)

Comment: How ironic is it that a question originally posed by Timothy Gowers is closed as opinion based?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I don't see the irony. Tim Gowers posted his opinion on his website. This was copied from there, but it's still his *opinion*. So, where's the irony?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I assumed that the question he posed was something he answered through research and was actually mathematically provable. I didn't think he posed an opinion-based answer. I thought it was just closed generically to get rid of the plagiarized question.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that a user copied parts from Tim Gowers' page at Cambridge University, and posted those as questions, without attribution.

Since the questions already have attracted a number of answers, straight deletion of the plagiarised content is not without its problems either. I have locked both questions until a decision how to resolve the situation is reached. Now is not the optimal time of the year for a speedy discussion, so the locked state lasts a bit longer than I hoped it would.

---

After discussing the matter with a CM, I've edited the questions to provide proper attribution and links to Tim Gowers' pages and unlocked them. Further improvements to the wording of the questions would not be unwelcome.

Comment: I understand the reason for locking, and agree with it. I was wondering where the "discussion" (speedy or otherwise) will take place.  Is it a moderators only thing, or will it be happening here on Meta?

Comment: Input from the community is welcome. There are some moderator-only aspects, but as for what to do with the _questions_, that's of public interest.

Comment: Regarding what to do with the question, to me a natural option seems to be to attribute and contextualize the copied text and to then ask for additional/alternative answers to Gowers's (rhetorical) question.

Comment: @quid Yes. I wasn't sure whether that would be sufficient (IANAL and so on). I got some CM feedback, and it probably is, so I've done my clumsy best with editing. Further improvements would be welcome.

Comment: @DanielFischer the fact that there was more than one instance in a short period of time  certainly adds a layer of consideration. Thanks for the edits. I noted one misdirected link and fixed it in addition to changing to the original Gowers's version a minor variation introduced by OP.

Comment: Thanks @quid. Copy-pasting links is difficult when so many are involved.

Comment: Are you a constructivist? Because "not be unwelcome" might not be equivalent to "welcome" if you reject the law of excluded middle.

Comment: No, @Asaf. Tertium non datur is not negotiable. I just occasionally am not entirely unsupportive of a little Litotes.

Comment: When/where was the decision made to make the post Community Wiki?

Comment: @mweiss I found the "multiple instances" aspect of things to be pretty sketchy; it strikes me as a way to gain a bit of reputation/good asking record quickly ("You mean, all I have to do is find questions asked by Gowers and post them like they're my own? Cool!"). I think CW is a fair way to not reward reputation. To be honest, it was legitimately multiple instances of plagiarism and I'm kind of hoping for something a bit more severe, for the user, than making the posts CW.

Comment: Indeed, I wish the site would be clearer about the fact that it considers plagiarism as a big no-no (if it does), through more effective reactions. The OP's misdeeds earned them around +160 reputation points, it seems, so the message to would-be plagiarists, so far, is actually that they do not risk much.

Comment: @Did though to be fair, persuing an issue of plagiarism (in this context) generally requires proof that one did not write the original work.We cannot always prove an author didn't write some work.All we can do is claim the post is horribly written due to being a blatant quote and leave it at that. After all, if an author wrote an unanswered question in closing remarks then why shouldn't one be able to ask that question here if it reasonable and noteworthy to ask? That's my opinion. We cannot jump to conclusions. So we have to make something that works for both plagiarism and "self-plagiarism".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What are you talking about? The OP reproduced several pages of Gowers' website verbatim and you want to argue that "we cannot jump to conclusions" and the like?

Comment: @pjs36 First we'd have to prove the OP didn't write the original work. Secondly, the answers made CW were made by people also quoting the work so the user only made 1 instance of plagiarism (cannot punish them for the responses they get, right). Thirdly, there's no reason the rep cannot be taken away.

Comment: @Did I see one paragraph in a question. How does that equate to being "several pages"? And my point is that a policy must extend to all users (to avoid potential discrimination or unfairness in general) which means if we punish one user for quoting we must punish *all* users for quoting without a source... even if it's their own material. Obviously he is not Timothy Gowers. My point is that future posters might use questions from their own works to see if unanswered questions they have might be answerable by others (or already answered).Hence the policy should try to avoid banning if possible.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Did you miss that *several* posts by this user copying without attribution the same website are involved? // Yes, a policy "must extend to all users" guilty of plagiarism. Are you mentioning this trivially true remark as an excuse to punish none?

Comment: @Did I only saw one question copied as mentioned in the question at the top. Ok, yeah. Posting this many questions is suspicious. However, *based on what I knew* I thought you were trying to ban a user for posting *one* question with copied material which is a bit excessive as first you would have to show good reason to believe they are not the one wrote that question in the first place. Plus, the TOS only refer to plagiarism in answers AFAIK. So technically this only counts as blatant spam of some random work. At least, until the TOS get revised so that we can ban *repeat* offenders.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Thanks for the noise.

Comment: @Did for instance, if we were to ban this guy but then Timothy Gowers himself came along and posted those questions (obviously assuming the duplicate rules are irrelevant) we'd have to also ban him because they both engaged in the same behavior. Yet the latter we might prefer not to ban or punish as (if anything) he's choosing not to link back to his document and avoid self-promotion.Hence why such a rule should have a clause (IMO) saying "the user must not be the original writer, or holder of the work's copyright".After all, a writer shouldn't have to cite himself on MSE if he chooses not to.

Comment: @Did Please do not be rude. Also our comments crossed. This is a discussion. I'm giving my opinion on how the rule change would have to go and why I feel the user (sadly) isn't punishable under the current system. If they do this again, then we have a reason to punish them. As of right now, the TOS just doesn't support banning them.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Yeah, and the extent of your misunderstanding of the situation is impressive.

Comment: @Did The user asked why this question was locked. Even if there were multiple question locked, the point is the same. The TOS say nothing about plagiarism within questions. It only mentions *answers* so until the TOS are revised or someone decides to file a formal complaint regarding their work being plagiarized the user hasn't actually committed an offense worthy of ban as it is stated in the rules. However, the moderator told them to stop and we can hope that they learn from their mistake and do not do it again as then they would be banned.

Comment: I certainly agree with the calls for a more severe punishment. Especially if the profile of the user says "Mathematics graduate". Sure, we all know there are parts of the world where academia is riddled with plagiarism and dishonesty. But at least on this site, I would want to hope that at least outright copying from someone else's website (never mind it was Gowers, that bit is irrelevant) will earn more than a "no more reputation on these questions for you", which is more of a punishment to the people who wrote the answers anyway.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck You say the TOS doesn't say anything about plagiarism in questions, but I believe there is nowhere made a distinction between questions and answers in the TOS. Also, the TOS says: "Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that (a) infringes, violates or otherwise interferes with any copyright or trademark of another party, [...] (c) infringes any intellectual property right of another or the privacy or publicity rights of another".

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Further, the content policy includes the following sentence:  "We reserve the right to immediately suspend, without notice, any content, account, [...] which we determine to be submitting [...] potentially damaging or disruptive content to the Network." Also, from the TOS: "Stack Exchange reserves the right to [...] suspend or terminate Subscriber’s right to use the Services at any time, [...] for any reason, [...] or for no reason at all." In particular, the last sentence gives SE  the right to suspend the user in question.